# how to add Linux library to my Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, monodevelop

I want to install this library "libgdiplus" with my deployment how to do this
standard Linux command as the following
"sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libgdiplus"

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin and mono this can be resolved using:
https://github.com/CoreCompat/libgdiplus-packaging

To understand System.Drawing.Common is the graphics library which ships as part of .NET Core. On macOS and Linux, it uses libgdiplus as its back-end.  This trick mirrors what mono did to implement `System.Drawing` (CoreCompat) for mac and Linux.

By adding CoreCompat libgdiplus packaging to our .net project we can remove the need to manually install libgdiplus as it will be loaded as a local native binary to our bin directory automatically.

This is available for MacOS as a nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing/

For Linux:
I believe we need sudo permissions as you are correct t suggest:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libgdiplus
```

**Update 2021 - Use .Net Core or .Net 5 instead:**

System.Drawing.Common as of version 5 and above now has reduced dependancies on external libgdiplus and works out-of-the-box in many more scenarios.  This is part of .NET Core rather than mono though.